# OCaml: unbound value load when trying to load module

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to load OCaml's default graphics module, but OCaml can't seem to load it or any other module. Here's what I'm trying:

```
> ocaml
    OCaml version 4.02.1

# load "graphics.cma";;
Error: Unbound value load
```

The problem persists no matter what module I try to load, so I believe that the problem is with the ocaml installation rather than with the module. I've tried reinstalling OCaml, but that hasn't helped either. I'm using OS X, and using homebrew to install ocaml. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29609483/1822310), and followed its instructions, but modules still won't load. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to type `#load`, not just `load`.

Note that the OCaml prompt is also `#`. So it's confusing.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# load "unix.cma";;
Error: Unbound value load
# #load "unix.cma";;
#
```

Answer (score 0):

Current state of the art if I dare say is

- using **opam** to install packages,
- **findlib** for using them in the toplevel,
- and **ocamlfind** for the compilation.

If your project is bigger you would use **ocamlbuild** (currently comes with the compiler) or others to build it.