# OCaml - Graphics module doesn't work

Tags: graphics, ocaml

I have a minimal program using the Graphics module that just does `open Graphics;; open_graph "";;`, and I'm building it with `ocamlbuild -package graphics test.native`. The compilation succeeds, but when I execute the .native file, nothing happens and the program just hangs until I interrupt it.

I'm running OS X 10.10. I've installed xquartz and ocaml (using `--with-x11`) using Homebrew and restarted several times. I've tried running [this minimal graphics program](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis120/current/graphics.shtml) as well with the same results. I've tried starting the xquartz application before executing, also with the same results. I'm sure that the graphics package installed correctly -- running 'ls `ocamlc -where`/graphics*`' shows the expected graphics.* files.

I'd really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Where did you see that you had to install OCaml with `--with-X11`? All the persons I know who had to install OCaml on Mac never did this. Did you try to install it with opam? (https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html#OSX)

Comment: in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435927/ocaml-unbound-graphics-module. Originally I'd installed ocaml with brew (`brew install ocaml`) - let me try reinstalling it with OPAM.

Comment: Have you installed the libx11-dev package?