# Why can't opam install the graphics package?

Tags: ocaml, opam

I tried to install the ocaml graphics package, but it fails. Any suggestions for how I can fix it?

```
~/Documents/Work/Code/OCaml with graphics: opam update

=-=- Updating package repositories =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   
[default: http] Command started
[default: http] Command started
[default] synchronized from https://opam.ocaml.org

~/Documents/Work/Code/OCaml with graphics: opam upgrade
Already up-to-date.

~/Documents/Work/Code/OCaml with graphics: opam install graphics
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗  install graphics 1.0

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   

=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   
[graphics: ocamlc graphics.cma] Command started
[ERROR] The compilation of graphics failed at "ocamlc -custom graphics.cma -o
        test".

#=== ERROR while installing graphics.1.0 ======================================#
# opam-version         1.2.2
# os                   darwin
# command              ocamlc -custom graphics.cma -o test
# path                 /Users/Tim/.opam/system/build/graphics.1.0
# compiler             system (4.04.0)
# exit-code            2
# env-file             /Users/Tim/.opam/system/build/graphics.1.0/graphics-14648-7afd23.env
# stdout-file          /Users/Tim/.opam/system/build/graphics.1.0/graphics-14648-7afd23.out
# stderr-file          /Users/Tim/.opam/system/build/graphics.1.0/graphics-14648-7afd23.err
### stderr ###
# File "_none_", line 1:
# Error: Cannot find file graphics.cma

=-=- Error report -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   
The following actions failed
  ∗  install graphics 1.0
No changes have been performed

=-=- graphics.1.0 troubleshooting -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   
=> This package checks whether the Graphics library was compiled.
```

Other than the missing graphics package, my ocaml install is working fine.

Here are the contents of the files in ~/.opam/system/build/graphics.1.0

First, graphics-14648-7afd23.err:

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Cannot find file graphics.cma
```

Then graphics-14648-7afd23.info:

```
# opam-version         1.2.2
# os                   darwin
# command              ocamlc -custom graphics.cma -o test
# path                 /Users/Tim/.opam/system/build/graphics.1.0
# compiler             system (4.04.0)
# env-file             /Users/Tim/.opam/system/build/graphics.1.0/graphics-14648-7afd23.env
# stdout-file          /Users/Tim/.opam/system/build/graphics.1.0/graphics-14648-7afd23.out
# stderr-file          /Users/Tim/.opam/system/build/graphics.1.0/graphics-14648-7afd23.err
```

And graphics-14648-7afd23.env:

```
PATH=/Users/Tim/.opam/system/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH=/Users/Tim/.opam/system/lib/toplevel
PERL5LIB=/Users/Tim/.opam/system/lib/perl5:
MANPATH=/Users/Tim/.opam/system/man:/opt/local/share/man:
OPAMSWITCH=system
OPAMUTF8MSGS=1
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Tim/.opam/system/lib/stublibs:/usr/local/lib/ocaml/stublibs
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=dumb
TMPDIR=/var/folders/kv/kmn525v16kb2mz2hrhq3q4mh0000gn/T/
BASHRC_HAS_BEEN_RUN=1
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.8tP8Ej926f/Render
EMACSDATA=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc
OLDPWD=/Users/Tim/Documents/Work/Code
EMACSPATH=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
USER=Tim
EMACS=t
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.EXKwsf0Dz0/Listeners
TERMCAP=
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
COLUMNS=190
BASH_PROFILE_HAS_BEEN_RUN=1
PWD=/Users/Tim/Documents/Work/Code/OCaml with graphics
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
EMACSLOADPATH=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/site-lisp:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/leim
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/Tim
LOGNAME=Tim
INFOPATH=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/info:
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.jPYPDR7RIj/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
INSIDE_EMACS=23.1.1,comint
EMACSDOC=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc
_=/usr/local/bin/opam
OPAM_PACKAGE_VERSION=1.0
OPAM_PACKAGE_NAME=graphics
MAKELEVEL=
MAKEFLAGS=
```

The final file, graphics-14648-7afd23.env, is empty.

Comment: Could you give us the contents of the `/Users/Tim/.opam/system/build/graphics.1.0/graphics-14648-7afd23.*` files?

Comment: Okay, I've added them.

Comment: Did you run ``eval `opam config env` ``? If you don't know about this command, run `opam init` and follow the instructions it outputs.

Comment: I think @nekketsuuu is correct `eval $(opam config env)` should do.

Comment: I ran `eval $(opam config env)` (I already had .bash_profile and .ocamlinit set up), and tried `opam install graphics` again, but got the same results as I had previously. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Then it's strange why `opam` uses system OCaml compiler, not opam's one. Which OCaml version do you `opam switch`?

Comment: I haven't done anything with `opam switch` so the compiler was chosen by the default installation.

Comment: cross-post on caml-list https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/caml-list/2018-02/msg00045.html

Comment: @TimLeonard Could you tell me the result of `ls ~/.opam/*/lib/ocaml/graphics.cma`?

Comment: ls: /Users/Tim/.opam/*/lib/ocaml/graphics.cma: No such file or directory

Comment: @TimLeonard Thanks. Then, currently `opam install graphics` is failed due to the non-existence of the Graphics library. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: this answer didn't solve OP's problem. But I think this answer is still valuable, so I leave this here.*

---

Install the OCaml compiler via OPAM, using `opam switch <version number here>` (Available version numbers are shown by `opam switch`). [The graphics package](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/graphics/graphics.1.0/) is a virtual package to check the availability of [the Graphics library](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libgraph.html), so `opam install graphics` will fail if there is no library on system's OCaml.

You can confirm the existence of the Graphics library by running `ls ~/.opam/*/lib/ocaml/graphics.cma`. If no file is found, then Graphics is not installed and therefore the failure of installation is the valid behavior. I don't know the exact reason why Graphics isn't installed, but maybe it's important that Graphics needs X11 to be installed. Especially, it's necessary to install XQuartz on macOS. See [Shoe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29609483/5989200) for details. Also, re-installation of OCaml via OPAM will be needed after that. We can reinstall OCaml by running:

```
opam switch reinstall <version number here>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't seem to have helped. I get
the same error with the same messages.

Comment: To summarize, `opam install graphics` only checks to see if the graphics library is built in. And it should be built in by `opam install ocaml`. But macOS doesn't include X11, and graphics requires X11, so I have to install XQuartz (the macOS version of X11) with `brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz` (and then restart my computer), and then reinstall ocaml with `brew reinstall ocaml --with-x11`. 

Then the graphics library should be included in ocaml, and `opam install graphics` should verify that it's available.

I tried it, and no joy: I still get `# Error: Cannot find file graphics.cma`.